Multi-Select People Picker Question - PowerApps form connected to SharePoint
I have a multi-select people picker field from SharePoint in my Canvas app.  This is an Approver field that the initial user users to populate their Approvers when submitting a form.  But it's multi select, so the number of Approvers will vary.  Each Approver is sent an email requesting that they navigate back to the form and provide a response in a Choice field.  But the issue is that each Approver will need their own section - identified by a Text Label with their displayname on it.  If there were only two approvers, then it's easy - I would just use the "First" and "Last" formulas to pull their display names into two labels.   But what would I do if there were 4 or 5 Approvers selected in that People Picker.  How could I tell a 4th and 5th Text Label to display those specific users' displaynames?
The flow which sends an email to all identified Approvers is simple.  I just Append to String variable, and that's all.  But splitting the display names into individual Text Labels is where I'm hung up.

Without having the full context of your app, this sounds like it would be best solved by using a gallery with a data source of ComboBoxName.SelectedItems to account for the variable number of approvers.
However, if for some reason that isn't an option, you could look into the use of the Index() formula. Something like Index(ComboBoxName.SelectedItems,4).DisplayName would give you the display name for the 4th person in your people picker.

THANK YOU.  That Index formula is exactly what I needed.
